# Do any of the KRE-O Transformers sets actually transform?

Tags: 3rd-party

[KRE-O, a LEGO-compatible brick toy, has several officially licensed Transformers models.](http://www.hasbro.com/kre-o/en_US/) I have two of the smaller ones and they do not actually "transform" - you take them apart and put them back together in a different form.

Do any of the sets use model functions to provide transformation, or are they all simply different models using the same bricks?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's an almost [20 minute video about the kre-o Optimus Prime at youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TRMDb7cmylY) where pretty much everything is shown in detail - except the transformation itself. I'm really sure that if this was possible without disassembling and building it from scratch then it would be shown here, so the answer seems to be: no.

Comment: I've recently seen a TV advert for these, and they are quite definite about the "Travel in vehicle form, then **REBUILD** into robot form".

Answer (score 6):

I've not bought any but nothing I've heard suggests they can, and looking at the designs I can't see how this would be possible.

Answer (score 4):

None of them transform.  You have to take them apart and rebuild them into each mode.  They are essentially 2 models that use some of the same bricks between each mode.

Answer (score 2):

I have built al of these sets, and I have to agree with everyone else on this one.

However! If you use a couple of the moving parts, or hack with some same-scale LEGO pieces, you can buid them to transform all by yourself.

The Optimus Prime set is actually potentially hackable enough to rebuild as a real transformer alone, but you won' t get it to look  like a "normal" transformer, nor its namesake.